# How to make online Payment For Multiple Invoices in odoo 8.0?

Tags: odoo, payment-gateway, payment, odoo-8, invoice

We have `Odoo 8.0` and Configured `Online Payment Gateway` . It works fine when we pay single `Invoice` at a time.

If customer have `3 Invoices` and He Wants to pay online all 3 at the same time, is there any way to do the same ??

Comment: That question has nothing to do with programming. You should ask the question in the [Odoo forum](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1).

Comment: I didn't get your point. In odoo eCommerce this is simple workflow  "Add to cart -> Process Checkout -> Confirm -> Pay now ". and it creates only one invoice at a time. I want to know that how you create the 3 Invoice at a time for the single user.